# Javascript: Risks in storing a function as string to Mongo and converting it later with new Function()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cron

My intention is to persistently store a function somewhere to call it later for a `node-cron` job if the server restarts or crashes, because these cron jobs do not persist when server restarts.

So I've researched pretty extensively the capabilities of storing functions in Mongo, but everything talks about running the function in the database itself. What I want is to run this function in my web server.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
var someObject = {b: "b"};
var funcString = "function(a) {var object = "+JSON.stringify(someObject)+"; object.a = a; return object; }";
someMongoCollection.insert({_id: "abc", func: funcString});
```

Some time later...

```
var funcDoc = someMongoCollection.find({_id: "abc"});
var myFunction = new Function(funcDoc.func);
var newObject = myFunction("a");
```

What are the vulnerabilities in this approach?
Are there better, safer solutions?

Comment: How does `new Function(str)` even work? I've tried it in chrome console and can't manage to get it working. In over 5 years of my js experience, I never once saw this approach. The only way you could get that (kind of) working is with `eval`.

Comment: And for the real question, why would you even want to store a function in a database? With a fixed function like this, you store the data (i.e. `someObject`) and when you want to call this function retrieve the data and pass it to the function. If the function is dynamic and can be defined by a user, the list of possible vulnerabilities is probably endless, you don't want to do that in any circumstances.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak It's not a JavaScript thing but a "MongoDB" thing. ( see details in [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) documentation) And actually in a somewhat pointless way, all `Function` really does is act as a basic wrapper for what is really a "srtring" or something "stringified" from and actual `function()` ( since this is JavaScript after-all ); It's also **wildly misunderstood** by newcomers and the general "misinterpretation" is trying to use in client code what was meant to be used "on the database" instead.

Comment: So whilst you appear to be trying to so something "similar to what you can do in the MongoDB shell", the only reason that environment supports the "loading" of such "functions" is **purely for debugging purposes**, and of course the purpose of general edit. Mostly speaking, severside JavaScript has be basically superseded by newer implemented features in MongoDB and is more of a relic than of practical use. There are some cases where you have no other option than to use as some things are not yet possible in the native DSL. But these get smaller with every new version.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak @Neil Lunn I realized after a while that storing the data only so I could pass it to the script function was the obvious answer, and by adding a `isDone` field to check if the document had already been processed by the cron job. I also added a `runOnInit` to the cron config to make the job run again if the server happens to restart (this happens on every deploy). Though, it would have been great to get an actual answer on what the exact vulnerabilities are and how they work.

Comment: For any program, there are more attack vectors than one could imagine. And in your case, where you're just pulling some data from the database and putting it inside a string which is then interpreted as a function, you just opened yourself for a bunch more. But to try and think of cases where this could be abused, you'd need a security expert. And I think the title "security expert" alone should be able to tell you that answer won't be cheap.